# Slow and fast variables in Non-linear Sigma model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, regularization, sigma-models

I am following Peskin Section 13.3, where they solve the nonlinear sigma model using Polyakov method. This system has Lagrangian
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2g^2}|\partial_\mu\vec{n}|^2,\tag{13.67}
\end{equation}
where $\vec{n}$ is a unit vector. To find the renormalization flow of this Lagrangian the authors use a derivation first done by Polyakov where the unit vector field is decomposed in slow and fast variables. The slow vector field $\tilde{n}^i$ is obtained by integrating the Fourier modes of $n^i$ in the range $0<|k|<b\Lambda$ and rescaling the result to get another unit vector. After that the relation between $n^i$ and $\tilde{n}^i$ is given by
\begin{equation}
n^i(x)=\tilde{n}^i(x)(1-\phi^2)^{1/2}+\sum_{a=1}^{N-1}\phi_a(x)e^i_a(x),\tag{13.88}
\end{equation}
where the $e^i_a$ are unit vectors orthogonal to $\tilde{n}^i$ and the $\phi_a$ are expansion coefficients. Until now this expansion is completely general, however the authors state that the coefficients $\phi_a$ are fast variables that only have Fourier components in the range $b\Lambda<|k|<\Lambda$. This make sense intuitively given that $\tilde{n}^i$ is constructed only from slow Fourier components. Nevertheless, I would like to have a more formal derivation that this construction gives $\phi_a$ with Fourier components only exactly in the given range. Can anyone help me with that? I tried to play with the equations without success.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/76882/gauge-fields-in-polyakovs-treatment-of-renormalization-for-nonlinear-sigma-mode).

Comment: Maybe you could try Polyakov's paper cited or his book. The surfeit of symbols can confuse you. Take N=3, so only two slow and large goldstons and one small and fast  "jiggler"  integrated out to modify the coupling increasing it (you are moving towards the infrared.) But asking for formal is against the seat-of-the-pants spirit of the exercise.